# What is the value of x where $x = R_1 - R_4 + R_3 - R_2$ in correspondence to the area of different circle regions?

Tags: geometry, inequality

Consider the circle $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$, where a is any positive number. Let $\mathscr L$ be the line y = b where b is a real number with |b| < a. The y-axis and $\mathscr L$ divide the circle into four regions. Suppose the area of the upper right region is $R_1$ and going counter-clockwise, the other regions have areas $R_2$, $R_3$, and $R_4$. If $X = R_1 - R_4 + R_3 - R_2$, what is true of $X$?

*This is not a homework question, it's a question from a mathleague competition that I did not understand. Please keep answers at the high school mathematics level.*

Comment: Did you draw a picture? Perhaps reordering the definition of $x$ as $x = R_1 + R_3 - (R+2 + R_4)$ might help you come up with the answer.

Comment: My main misunderstanding of this problem is that $\mathscr L$ seems to represent an arbitrary line that crosses through perpendicular to the y-axis at any point within or tangent to the circle. I'm not completely sure what to draw a picture of even. It's probably something simple and I'm misreading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle is at the origin, hence symmetric along y-axis and y divides $C$ into two equal regions $R_{l}$ and $R_{r}$.

Let $\mathcal{L}$ divide $R_{l}$ into $R_{2} = R_{lt}$, $R_3 = R_{lb}$, and $R_{r}$ into $R_1 = R_{rt}, R_4 = R_{rb}$.

By symmetry $R_1 = R_2$ and $R_3 = R_4$, therefore $R_1 - R_4 = R_2 - R_3$ and $x = 0$.